# Shell script is omitting the escape character while returning the response payload for a CURL call

Tags: shell, curl, api

I have a shell script making a cur call that returns a response JSON payload containing a URL value with `\` character in it as it returns the encoded value for a symbol like `=`. However, the echo of the response is removing the `\`. Is there a way to get that character as well?

shell script:

```
curl -k -w "\n%{http_code}" -S -s -X GET \
            -H "Accept: application/json" \
            -u "<<Auth>>" \
"https://<<url>>" | {
    read body
    read code
    
    if [ "x$code" = "x200" ]
    then
      echo "$body" 
    else
      echo "ERROR:$code:$body"
    fi
}
```

The response is this:

```
{"param1":"val1","param2":{"p1":"v1","p2":"v2", "URL":"<<someString>>//<<host>>:<<port>>;extenstionu003dValue"}}
```

The last part of thevalue for the url is actually `extension=value`, but as it returns the encoded value it should return `\u003d`. The shell is cutting the `\`. Could someone please suggest me a way to have the `\` as well included in the response?

Comment: Which shell, specifically? in bash, you should use `read -r` to preserve backslash sequences

Comment: @steeldriver without `-r`, the `read` from any bourne-like shell will strip the backslashes, not just that from bash. With a standard shell (not with bash), `echo` may also expand backslash escapes in its arguments, even without `-e`.

Comment: thanks @steeldriver. it works

Comment: @user414777 would you like to write an answer? my experience with other shells / other implementations of `echo` is limited

Comment: Also, @steeldriver, just wondering, is there a way to get the `=` sign instead of the encoded one from the response? A direct API call from the browser works fine but curl in my `.sh` file gives this encoded one

Comment: @steeldriver I think that your "you should use `read -r` ..." is perfect as an answer to this question. There are already plenty of rambling answers about shell arcana that nobody reads ;-) For the `echo`, you can check with dash, the `/bin/sh` of Debian, Ubuntu: `/bin/dash -c 'echo "a\rb"'`

Comment: @SRS for `\uXXXX` in bash, simply `printf` would do: `printf '%b\n' 'a\u003db'` => `a=b`.

Comment: @user414777 OK I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the shell's `read` builtin treats `\` as an escape character (although since `\u` doesn't have a special meaning, it becomes literal `u`):

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'extension\u003dvalue' | { read body; echo "$body"; }
extensionu003dvalue
```

You can turn off backslash processing using the `-r` option:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'extension\u003dvalue' | { read -r body; echo "$body"; }
extension\u003dvalue
```